# INSERT / UPDATE Mysql Single Form

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 database tables

> tbl1 users ---------- tbl2 gamesystems
>   
> uid field  -------------  gs_uid field

the 2 tables are tied together by the user_id..

now i want tbl2 to only be updated able and fields are not required.. with the exception of the gs_uid when they update there system.

my only issue is i need to insert the user_id into the gs_uid.

```
function game_system()
{    
   if(isset($_POST['game_system'])) {


            $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
            $motherboard = escape($_POST['motherboard']);
            $processor = escape($_POST['processor']);            
            $memory = escape($_POST['memory']);
            $graphics = escape($_POST['graphics']);
            $harddrive = escape($_POST['harddrive']);
            $power = escape($_POST['powersupply']);
            $cooling = escape($_POST['cooling']);
            $towercase = escape($_POST['towercase']);


            $sql = "INSERT INTO gamesystem(gs_uid, motherboard, processor, memory, graphics, harddrive, powersupply, cooling, towercase) ";
            $sql .= "VALUES('{$user_id}','{$motherboard}','{$processor}','{$memory}','{$graphics}','{$harddrive}','{$power}','{$cooling}','{$towercase}') ";
            $result = query($sql);   


        }
   }
```

Comment: you have put condition that edit request comes than update query else insert query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If gs_uid is the primary key of table 'gamesystem' , then this field should not accept empty data.

Otherwise, if gs_uid is NOT the key, what's the primary key of this table? In case of UPDATE, you'll need to specify which row you'd like to update, otherwise the system will not know how to do so.

the SQL should looks like below

```
UPDATE "gamesystem"
SET "gs_uid" = $user_id
WHERE YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN = SPECIFIC VALUE;
```